# I'm making a discord trivia bot in Python. How is it possible the bot can see if a variable is equal to what someone typed in chat?

Tags: python, discord.py

Whenever I'm trying to check if a discord message is equal to a variable it always says `'unexpected token discord'`. I'm quite new to programming so I don't really know much but I know the bare basics. 
Note: All of the code does what it's supposed to do up until the last two lines.

```
import discord
import random 
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import time
import asyncio
import pickle

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix =  'r!')



@client.command(aliases=['Quiz'])
async def quiz(ctx):
    if Can_Start == True: print("Quiz Initiated")
    await ctx.send("Quiz Starting...")
    time.sleep(2)

    Decider = str(random.randint(1,2))
    print("Question " + str(Decider))

    mylines = []
    with open ('Questions/Q' + Decider + '.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
        for myline in myfile:
            mylines.append(myline)

        Question = (mylines[0]) 
        print(Question)
        Answer = (mylines[1])
        print(Answer)

    await ctx.send(Question)
    print("Question was sent.")

        if discord.Message == Answer
            print("Answer Correct")
```

I want the console to say `'Answer correct'` when the user enters the correct answer which is located in the text files.

Comment: Can you send the full stacktrace i.e. what is printed as an error?

Comment: The whole code is wrong (blocking sleep, magic Can_Start , treating discord.Message  as sent message ... ) but let's stick to your error. Just read it and I'm pretty sure we can agree that your `bot.run` function is in wrong place or using the wrong token.

Comment: if message.content == Answer
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: this is only part of the code, i forgot to include the variables in this but on VS 2019, the variables are there

Comment: The indentation error is because you are using an unnecessary indent, it’s not in a loop or function so there’s no need for an Indent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I think you are getting that error is because you are trying to compare a discord.Message object to your answer, not the message itself, if you try using `'print discord.Message'` all you get is

```
<class 'discord.member.Member'>
```

I suggest learning about [classes](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) in Python.

So instead of comparing discord.Member to your answer, You can use [client.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) instead

```
await ctx.send(Question)

def check(m):
  return m.author == ctx.message.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel

try:
  message, author = client.wait_for('message', check =       check, timeout = 60)
  if message.content == Answer:
    await ctx.send('Answer correct.')
  else:
    await ctx.send('Answer wrong')
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
  await ctx.send('Times out')
```

We can pass the `'message'` argument to client.wait_for so that the bot waits for a message, you can add a cool timeout in seconds, and also a `check`, which you can make a function to check whether the user who sends the message is the original author and it’s in the same channel.
The timeout and check parameters are optional.

Hope you got what you’re looking for!